# Developer account verification problems for creating new app

Tags: facebook, verification

**Setup:**

1. I have been struggling most of the afternoon, trying to understand why FB won't allow me to create a new Login App.
2. Finally(!) figured out it is because I have a *business* account, not a *personal* account. Of course FB didn't tell me this.  They just kept looping me around in circles from the Developer area back to my Account page.  No explanations.  No error messages.  Just redirects.
3. Through this process, I did register as a Developer and they required me to verify a text msg sent to my cell phone -- which makes NO sense, because evidently I had the WRONG KIND of account in the first place!
4. So, I created a second account -- this time a *personal* account.  And again they are asking me to verify my Developer registration with a cell phone.

**Problem:**

Since the phone was already used for the aforementioned business account, FB is rejecting my number and it appears I'm completely screwed.  I only have one phone.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to disconnect my phone from the business account so that it can be attached to my personal account?
2. Or is there a way to attach my already-verified Developer account (for lack of a better term) to my new personal account?
3. If neither of the above are possible, am I just out of luck?

Comment: Hi @MitchWheat. It's fine that you don't care, but I know I am not the only person who has struggled with this. Putting my personal frustrations aside, the questions are valid.

Comment: I don't care because it is NOT a programming question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy the cheapest prepaid starter and use it for verification.

Comment: Mikolaj, I think you are correct.  As ridiculous as it seems to resort to such measures, your idea is the most plausible solution to the problem.  Thank you for your constructive vs. destructive approach to this topic.

Comment: you could also verify with a credit card

Comment: You could also use someone else's phone number temporarily, to verify.